# Since + present perfect/ help

Tags: present-perfect

Are my sentences correct?
Hi there!

1.Since I **have had** more time, I am happy *(I still have more time)*

2.Since I **started having** more time, I am happy

3.Since I **have had** believed in my father I am even more happy

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sentences 1 and 2 are absolutely correct.

Sentence 3 is not; I'd suggest "started to believe" (as in sentence 2). ("Since I've believed in my father" feels very slightly strange—not wrong, but also not something I'm likely to say.)